# How would you say 16 and 18 with the counter mai?

Tags: pronunciation, counters

My textbook [Japanese from zero 1, George Trombley] gives 6 and 8 as roku mai and hachi mai.

But then gives 16 and 18 as じゅうろっまい juu rommai and じゅうはっまい juu hammai.

Is this correct ?

I am only learning but it sounds wrong to me. I would imagine it would be juu roku mai and juu hachi mai.

If so then does 26/28, 36/38, etc. follow the same pattern ?

Comment: What’s the textbook? This looks very wrong

Comment: I've added the textbook reference.

Comment: If possible, could you post a screenshot of the pages?  This is so wrong, I'm left wondering if it might be a printing artifact like a smudge or an accidental fold.

Comment: That's an embarrassing error...

Comment: I would personally get rid of that textbook.

Comment: On [a related YouTube video about this lesson from the creator directly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFCbjJt0qQE), Catharine Hayne [commented](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFCbjJt0qQE&lc=UgzVVGWAoYJ8rMOwant4AaABAg) on this matter, and they acknowledged it was a typo: "*It’s a typo. It should be じゅうろくまい and じゅうはちまい. Glad you caught it.*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noted, 6枚 should be read as ろくまい, and 8枚 should be read as はちまい.

Similarly, 16枚 should be read as じゅうろくまい, and 18枚 should be read as じゅうはちまい.

I have no idea why your textbook would render these as じゅうろっまい and じゅうはっまい.  Neither pronunciation is correct -- these aren't even dialectal variants, so far as I'm aware; they're just wrong.

PS: The larger numbers you asked about, like 26枚・28枚 etc, would still use the standard ～ろくまい・～はちまい pronunciations.

Comment: 「ろっまい」って、「ろんまい」と読むんですかね

Comment: @AeonAkechi, presumably そうでしょう。でも、鼻音には促音を示す「っ」が付かないから、あの教科書は間違えているように見えますが。